# Why isn't my 'Else' expression showing in this scenario when i try to run my code?

Tags: python

I am a beginner when it comes to coding. I am trying to run a program on python that takes in kilometers(user input) and returns it in miles(output). I know how to do the task but I wanted to challenge myself by using if statements to check if the user has entered a number:

```
Kilometers = input("Please insert number of Kilometers: ")
if type(Kilometers) == int or float:
    print("This is equivalent to", float(Kilometers)/1.609344, "Mile(s)")
else:
    print("This is not a number")
```

I understand that whatever the user inputs will be saved as a string. However, whenever I run the code, the program always tries to convert the input into miles.

I have specified in the if statement that the type has to equal a float or an int, so shouldn't the output always be "This is not a number" until I change the first line to:

```
Kilometers = float(input("Please insert number of Kilometers: "))
```

or

```
Kilometers = int(input("Please insert number of Kilometers: "))
```

Comment: You might prefer to use `isinstance`, as described here: [Python check if isinstance any type in list?](/a/33311330/4518341) That'll allow for subclasses. Or you might prefer to [ask the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341).

Comment: I'll give you a hint: bool(float)) -> True

Comment: `if type(Kilometers) == int or float` is not doing what you think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are multiple issues with this code; please read each linked duplicate carefully. Aside from the other comments: `input` will give you *a string, no matter what*. You seem to understand this: "I understand that whatever the user inputs will be saved as a string." Therefore, you should expect `type(Kilometers)` to be `str` - yes?

Comment: @Karl Yeah, OP's aware that `type(Kilometers)` will be `str`, so they're expecting the `else` to always run. But the `or` is not doing what they expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming if statements in Python, each condition must be fully rewritten. For example, you would write `if type(Kilometers) == int or type(Kilometers) == float` rather than `if type(Kilometers) == int or float`. Another important thing in your code is that if someone inputs `5.5`, you would expect a float value, but Python interprets that to be a string. In order to circumvent this, you can use a try/except clause like this:

```
Kilometers = input("Please insert number of Kilometers: ")
try:
    Kilometers = float(Kilometers)
    print("This is equivalent to", Kilometers/1.609344, "Mile(s)")
except ValueError:
    print("This is not a number")
```

What this is doing is trying to set `Kilometers` as a float type, and if the user inputs a string that cannot be interpreted as a float, it will cause a ValueError, and then the code inside `except` will run. You can find more on try/except clauses here: [Python Try Except - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

One more thing I noticed is that you should name your variables according to the standard naming conventions, so `Kilometers` should be `kilometers`. You can find more on the naming conventions here: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)